# How to call a verification function from views to templates?

Tags: python, django

I have a function to check if the user is a staff:

```py
class VerificateUser():
    def allowed_user(request):
        if request.user.is_staff:
            return True
```

In my template, I’m going to show this section only for staff users, but this is not working.

```html
{% url if not allowed_user %}
<h1>
    Welcome to the show
</h1>
```

````
If do something like it, works:

```html
{% if not request.user.is_staff %}
<h1>
    Welcome to the show
</h1>
````

But I need to use a view function to clean my code because I’m probably going to add more conditionals.

Comment: This isn't really an `HTML` question

Comment: What is the structure you are working with? Function based views or class based views?

Comment: class based views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using a class-based view then I would suggest updating the `context` dictionary which you could use in the `html` template to determine whether the `user` is allowed or not. For example, Within the `views.py`.

```
class VerificateUser():
    # Update the context
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        # Call the allowed_user() and return whatever value, passing that value it to the context variable
        context['allowed_user'] = self.allowed_user()

    return context

    # Checking if the user is allowed here
    def allowed_user():
        if self.request.user.is_staff:
            return True

        return False
```

Now within the `html` file, you can reference that `allowed_user` from the context variable.

```
{% if allowed_user %}
    <h1>Hi, you are allowed to see here...</h1>
{% endif %}
```

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this sort of thing in many ways, but simply you can do by the following way-

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
    <p>Welcome,{{request.user.first_name}} </p>          
{% endif %}
```

`request` object is by default available in all of your Django templates context.